# Read WebPages and export specific data

Tags: php, c++, curl, split, strtok

Using c++ have to read a specific data from a webpage (a soccer player page), and i want to create a file with all the player with their team.
first of all i import all page code with CURL into a file.txt, than, after i read file.txt i sent all the content in a string. Now i have to split all the name and their specific team. How can i split it? i have to delete all HTML/PHP tags.

(example:  **<'p name""> Ronaldo <\p>**  ---> **Ronaldo**) Can anyone help me please?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file text" for ideas on how to parse.  You may want to search for a library that can parse Web pages.

Comment: So what have you done so far? [I personally wouldn't use C++ for this - using php or some other simple scripting language is probably a whole lot easier, unless you know A LOT of C++ and don't know any other language] - also, dpeending on the format of the page, it's quite plausible you need some "flexibility" in the parsing/splitting logic (I have written a few pieces of "read something from a webpage" with varying degree of difficulty - none of that is in C or C++)